# parse error php en html

Tags: php, html

intento de meter codigo html dentro de php, pero me sale este error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ',' or ';' on line 3

Mi codigo php

```
 <?
 echo'
 <div class="custom-text js-custom-text-carousel" data-slick="".'.""{"speed": 1000, "autoplaySpeed": 3000}"".'."">
    ';
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

En vez de hacer concatenaciones complicadas, mejor [escapa los caracteres](https://www.php.net/manual/es/regexp.reference.escape.php).

Entonces esa línea, siguiendo [el formato](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), se puede reescribir así:

```
echo '<div class="custom-text js-custom-text-carousel" data-slick=\'{"speed": 1000, "autoplaySpeed": 3000}\'>';
```

Lo cual imprime:

```
<div class="custom-text js-custom-text-carousel" data-slick='{"speed": 1000, "autoplaySpeed": 3000}'>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias si me funciono